# Make Mathematica input things on a website and take the data out

Tags: web-access, interoperability, javascript

So I found a website that calculates polynomials that I need it intakes a word of a's and b's say aabba and outputs a polynomial. Here is the website: [http://www.math.stonybrook.edu/~moira/NewApps/Fricke%20Polynomial/fricke.html](http://www.math.stonybrook.edu/%7Emoira/NewApps/Fricke%20Polynomial/fricke.html)

I do not know how to use javascript,html,css or anything like that so I am not sure how to import this into Mathematica. I have asked it on stackoverflow with hopes of putting jt into Mathematica but no answer thus far. Thus I was wondering if I can perhaps write code in Mathematica that goes on that website, inputs a word, and outputs the polynomial. An API of a sort. Is  that possible?

Comment: You could try with `WebExecute` but it does not sound efficient. If you open the site and browser dev tools, navigate to Sources you can see Polynomial.js with `function Fricke` so you can try to rewrite it with mma. Another take would be to fetch those js sources and `ExternalEvaluate` it through NodeJS.

Comment: @Kuba I have copied the js sources (all three of them) and made them into a single code. However, it does not work. I presume it has something to do with it being tied to the html code. I only know Mathematica so I trying things blindly here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- [ConfigureNodeJSForExternalEvaluate](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/workflow/ConfigureNodeJSForExternalEvaluate.html)

```
ClearAll[x, y, z]

session = StartExternalSession@"NodeJS";

sources = Import[#, "Text"] & /@ {
    "http://www.math.stonybrook.edu/~moira/NewApps/Fricke%20Polynomial/Word.js",
    "http://www.math.stonybrook.edu/~moira/NewApps/Fricke%20Polynomial/Polynomial.js"
};

ExternalEvaluate[session, sources];

fricke = ExternalEvaluate[session, "Fricke"];

frickeStringToExpr[str_String]:= str // 
  StringReplace[ x : LetterCharacter ~~ n : DigitCharacter .. :> ( StringTemplate[" ``^``"][x, n]) ] // 
  ToExpression
```

---

```
string = "aabba";

fricke[string]["data"] // frickeStringToExpr
```

> ```
> 3 x - x^3 - x y^2 - y z + x^2 y z
> ```

Comment: You are a saint. It worked! (I did have to register the NodeJS manually for some reason). Dozgonna wdzięczność :)